# css justify content issue in footer

Tags: css, layout, margin, footer, justify

I have a footer and want that my list items are left justified with my `h3`. Is there a way to do it?

Now `company` and `social` and `other` are a bit more left than the rest. I already put `justify-content: center` but it seems like the headers have a different center than my list items. Hope somebody can help me.

[image]

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #5490dd;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
}

.footer-items {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
}

.footer-column {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 33.33%;
  /*drittelt den Platz im footer*/
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-column ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*entfernt Anstriche*/
}

.footer-column ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.footer-column ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*entfernt das die Links unterstrichen sind*/
  color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <div class="footer-items">

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Über Uns</a></li>
        <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="other">other</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a>other1</a></li>
        <li><a>other2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: also I suggest to use `flex-grow: 1;` instead `width: 33.33%`, as I had sugested in your previous question, get the power from `flexbox`. If you want to use `width` use at least `calc(100% / 3)`, but `flexbox` properties more convinient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need `ul` `li` without their styles? Aslo `ul` has its defaults, which maybe you don't want to use. Use `div`.

Look into the snippet.

I added `padding-bottom` to `.footer-column` and changed `ul` `li` to `div` in `html` and `css`

If you want left alignment - remove `text-align: center;`

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #5490dd;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
}

.footer-items {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
}

.footer-column {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 33.33%;
  /*drittelt den Platz im footer*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer-column div {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.footer-column div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*entfernt das die Links unterstrichen sind*/
  color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <div class="footer-items">

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
      <div><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></div>
      <div><a href="about.html">Über Uns</a></div>
      <div><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="social">Social</h3>

      <div><a>Twitter</a></div>
      <div><a>Instagram</a></div>
      <div><a>Reddit</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer-column">
      <h3 class="other">other</h3>

      <div><a>other1</a></div>
      <div><a>other2</a></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```